# EJB Timer Service: order of timeouts

Tags: timeout, ejb

I have two timeouts defined: 
timeout A - every 30 seconds
timeout B - every 2 minutes

```
// scheduled for timeout A (every 30sec)
@Stateless
public class MyBeanA {
   (...)

   @Timeout
   public void onTimeoutA(javax.ejb.Timer timer) {
     // (...)
   }
}

// scheduled for timeout B (every 2min)
@Stateless
public class MyBeanB {
   (...)

   @Timeout
   public void onTimeoutB(javax.ejb.Timer timer) {
     // (...)
   }
}
```

It's easy to notice, that after every 2 minutes, both timeouts will be fired. I'd like to make sure that in this case, timeout A will be fired before timeout B:
(30sec): timeoutA, (60sec): timeoutA, (90sec): timeoutA, (120sec): timeoutA, timeoutB

Is it possible with standard EJB (3.0) Timer Service API?
My application server is JBoss.

Thanks in advance,
Piotr

Comment: Maybe you could just allow A to control it all. I.e. Run A every 30 seconds and every 4th event (120 seconds) let it do its processing and then call the appropriate method on Bean B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to order timers like that.  You could do it manually:

1. Schedule a single-action timer for A in 30 seconds with info=1
2. Schedule an interval timer for B for 120 seconds
3. When A fires with info=1, schedule a single-action timer for A in 30 seconds with info=2
4. When A fires with info=2, schedule a single action timer for A in 30 seconds with info=3
5. When A fires with info=3, don't reschedule
6. When B fires, call A, then do the work for B.  Schedule a single-action timer for A in 30 seconds with info=1

Answer (score 0):

Solution I used is very similar to the one given by bkail. 
There is one ejbTimeout() method scheduled to be fired every 30seconds. Timeout is scheduled with Serializable object containing counter:

```
createTimer(Date initialExpiration, long intervalDuration, Serializable info)
```

Every time ejbTimeout is called, counter is increased. If it reach 3, then method which should be fired after 2 minutes is invoked, and also counter is set back to 0. It works as below:

```
ejbTimeout after 30sec (counter == 0): call A(); counter++;
ejbTimeout after 30sec (counter == 1): call A(); counter++;
ejbTimeout after 30sec (counter == 2): call A(); counter++;
ejbTimeout after 30sec (counter == 3): call A(); call B(); counter = 0;
```

Comment: This will probably work in most cases, but I'll note that Timers are persistent in EJB 3.0, but the counter variable will not be.